# How can I fix this error in react related to react-router

Tags: reactjs, router

please tell me I can’t figure it out for 4 days, no matter how hard I try, the same error pops up, no matter what library I add to my application, they understand the react-router, and each compilation ends with Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   With this mistake, could you tell me how to fix it correctly and may be somehow connected with the installation of the library, or my house with a react-router is simply not supported, I will be grateful for your help!

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={<Main />} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={<Users />} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={<Contacts />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

const Main = () => {
  <div>
    <h1>I am Main page! Hello user!</h1>
  </div>
}
const Users = () => {
  <div>
    <h1>I am Users page! Hello user!</h1>
  </div>
}
const Contacts = () => {
  <div>
    <h1>I am Contacts page! Hello user!</h1>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code that causes this bug? are you calling a hook in a class somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem because it doesn't look like you are using a hook anywhere, but your components need to have a `return` statement or be enclosed in parenthesis

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>I am Main page! Hello user!</h1>
  </div>
);
```

OR

```
 const Main = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>I am Main page! Hello user!</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to accurate exactly what you are doing wrong without your's code sample.

So, somethings that are worth checking before edit your post...

- Archives extensions needs to end with `.jsx` or if typescript `.tsx`

This may not be your case, but it is worth knowing. Some hooks throws errors when using it inside another function
ex:

```js
function App() {

//right
const history = useHistory();


function myFunction(){
// wrong
const history = useHistory();

 history.push('/');
}


return (
...jsx
)
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

an unrelated tip - a good linter like ESLint will help you make a good, bug free code. At first, it will complain a lot, but that's because your code needs a lot of improvement in terms of quality.

If you used Create React App, it should be already installed, just turn it on in your editor.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30703080)